# Mute all notifications for Microsoft Teams?

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios

Is it possible to mute **all** notifications in Microsoft Teams on iPhone?

Ideally there would be some mode that would allow me to mute all Teams notifications for one hour, two hours, eight hours, etc.

Logging in to Microsoft Teams on iPhone is quite unwieldy, so it would be convenient to stay logged in at all times. However, I rarely want to get notifications from the Teams app *except for when I work remotely*.

I also don’t want to adjust notification settings per team since I am member of quite many teams. And I don’t want to set the phone in silent mode since I still want to hear calls and SMS notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually turn off notifications for this app in the settings :

Settings > Notifications > Microsoft Teams > Allow Notifications

There's no built-in way to mute for X hours, but you may be able to do it with Shortcuts.